# Error when trying to view designer in windows store app c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am getting the below error messages when I try and view any xaml design page in my project, can anyone tell me what it means?

```
System.Exception
Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.

Windows cannot install package App.a9a122e61.a5503.a4c46.a9cbd.ad0f269743658 because this package depends on another package that could not be found. This package requires minimum version 0.0.0.0 of framework Microsoft.VCLibs.110.00.Debug published by any publisher to install. Provide the framework along with this package.
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, FrameworkName targetFramework, String identifier, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedExportProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateExportProvider(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, ICatalogFactory catalogFactory, IExportFilter filter)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<StartTask>b__6()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Thanks,

Callum

UPDATE

After about an hour of searching; I have resorted to using blender as it work fine in there.

For people who don't know how to do this:

Open the aspx page -> View -> Open with Blend...

Comment: I would try doing a repair on visual studio to fix the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAML editor failes, Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.Windows cannot install package App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307511/xaml-editor-failes-package-failed-updates-dependency-or-conflict-validation-wi)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but since there is no answer, that might help someone.
I answered this same question here :

[XAML editor failes, Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.Windows cannot install package App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307511/xaml-editor-failes-package-failed-updates-dependency-or-conflict-validation-wi/29515196#29515196)

Your issue says that you're missing this package : 
"Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.Debug" **(in your case VCLibs.110)** You can solve it by adding in the visual studio installer. "Core Tools for Visual C++ Mobile Development" which is in the branch "Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development".

[image]