# XAML editor failes, Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.Windows cannot install package App

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have just installed Visual Studio Express 2013 update 4 on Windows 8.1 OS, and started a new Windows Phone App project. When I tried to open a `View Designer` page of any `XAML`, it fails with the following error message:

```
System.Exception
Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.
Windows cannot install package App.af631a335.af069.a4bf5.a81c7.af4c34f85cb29 because this package depends on another package that could not be found. This package requires minimum version 0.0.0.0 of framework Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.Debug published by any publisher to install. Provide the framework along with this package.
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, FrameworkName targetFramework, String identifier, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<StartTask>b__6()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I Have tried repairing visual studio But no use.

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533964/error-when-trying-to-view-designer-in-windows-store-app-c-sharp) Question, But no use.

I have uninstalled Visual Studio 2013 Express Update 4 and installed again but no use .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it by enabling the `developer licence`. I found the details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue says that you're missing this package : "Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.Debug"
You can solve it by adding in the visual studio installer.
"Core Tools for Visual C++ Mobile Development" which is in the branch "Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development".

[image]